# server side - bootsrap typeahead internal error on first load - with laravel http error not found

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm trying to use twitter bootstrap typeahead in a form and using a server side query to fetch records from a database.
I have the feature up and running, it fetches data once I start entering a search after 3 characters which is great.
However on first loading the page I get a 500 error exception from the main bootstrap-typeahead.js script that is:

```
NotFoundHttpException
```

I do not get an error when using the page - just on first load.

So, I assume the script makes an initial call to probably the query on the server side with a blank query which may be the cause. I've tried putting in defaults into the route and search function on laravel but still the error.

The page works as it is but I want to not have this error. Where can I start to look? I'm not even sure though what request is being made by the script to throw the erro...

Here's the script - initialising the typeahed function:

```
$('#typeahead').typeahead({
source: function(query, process) {

    if(query===null) {
        query = 'aaa';
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: '/customers/typeahead/'+query,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        //data: "query=" + query,
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            customers = [];
            map = {};
            $.each(data, function(i, customer) {
                //map object with unique name for each returned customer
                map[customer.first_name + ' ' + customer.last_name + ': ' + customer.email + ' - ' + customer.id ] = customer;
                customers.push(customer.first_name + ' ' + customer.last_name + ': ' + customer.email + ' - ' + customer.id);
            });
            process(customers);
        }
    });
},
minLength: 3,
updater: function(item) {
    alert("selected");
    id = map[item].id;
    fetchCustomer(id);
    return item;
}

});
```

Here's the laravel route:

```
Route::get('customers/typeahead/{qry?}', function ($qry = 'a') {

    return Customer::customerTypeahead($qry);

});
```

Here's the laravel model function:

```
static public function customerTypeahead($qry) {

    //$qry = Input::get('query');
    $qry='%'.$qry.'%';

    $customers=Customer::where('first_name','like',$qry)
        ->orWhere('last_name','like',$qry)
        ->orWhere('email','like',$qry)
        ->get(array('first_name','last_name','email','id'))->toJson();

    return $customers;

}
```

Any ideas what could throw the initial error and how to start tracking?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the full website url to jQuery's url object. If you want dynamic url you could add

```
<script>var WEBSITE_URL = {{ URL::to('/') }};</script>
```

before your js application, then

```
...
$.ajax({
    url: WEBSITE_URL + 'customers/typeahead/'+query,
...
```

Try to use firebug to see what's sent and what's returned so you can better locate where's the error.

Comment: I added the additional code but the error continues. I'm going to try and set up in fiddle to see if I can replicate. Thank you